# HTML - include php

Tags: javascript, php

For example i can import javascript:

`<script src="script.js"/>`

or include:`<script>//some script</script>`

I can import php like this:

`<form action="file.php">`

But how to include it?

I mean not to create additional php file.
Like this `<form action=<?php /*php there*/ ?>>`
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking about. Usually, PHP is *generating* the HTML.

Comment: PHP is a server side language and cannot be explicitly included in an HTML page. You must make that HTML page a PHP page by changing the extension from `.html` to `.php` then you can use php.

Comment: A form action is not "`importing php`"

Comment: @nicael, revise your question to be more clear. More example code or description would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML file cannot include a php file in the sense you're asking, because a .php file is being processed by the server and is (generally) outputting HTML.

Your example...

**I can import php like this:**

```
<form action="file.php">
```

is *not* "importing" php, it is directing the form POST to a php file to be processed, which then outputs HTML as its response.

In general, when doing PHP programming, you are writing .php files *instead of* writing .html files. If something needs to use PHP code it should be in a .php file, not a .html file which normally has completely static content.

There *is* a way to have your PHP processor act upon .html files, and that is to configure Apache (or whatever your webserver is) to hand .html files to PHP in the same way it is configured to handle .php files — but then you are incurring the overhead of processing every .html file whether or not it actually has PHP code in it.

Comment: @nicael - if this explanation answers your question I'd appreciate an "accept"

Answer (score 0):

`<?php include "file-name.php" ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are having `.php` etension for your file

```
  <?php include "filename.php" ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the different ways of including a php file.

```
<?php include 'file.php';?>
//OR
<?php include_once 'file.php';?>
//OR
<?php require('file.php');
//OR
<?php require_once('file.php');

 looking at your code,  you are trying to set a file in the action attribute
 of a form.  If that is true then you do not need to include the file. 
 On form submission the script in the action will be executed.
```